# Node server is not responding to the Http requests made while MongoDb Map Reduce job is in process

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, nodes, mean-stack

I am developing an application in MEAN Stack. There is a heavy calculation required in my application which is done using MAP REDUCE in mongodb.
Map reduce takes 20 sec for the calculation.
If any other user sends any http request to the node server, it gets stuck till MR completes.
Now my question is. Who is blocking the server from responding?

1. Is it because of node thread is busy during MR operation?
2. Does mongoose performing any job during MR?

Here is the code

```
var mapFunction = function() {

        var key = this.id;
        emit(key, 1);
    };

    var reduceFunction = function(key, values) {
        return values*5;
    };

    var finalizeFunction = function (key, reducedVal) {

      var CalcData;

        CalcData = calculationFn(reducedVal);

        return CalcsData ;
    };

    motors.mapReduce({
        map: mapFunction,
        reduce: reduceFunction,
        finalize: finalizeFunction,
        out : {replace : "search_results"}
        //out: { inline: 1 }

    }, function (err, results) {
        var output = [];
        console.log("Done with Search");
        next(undefined, output);
    });
```

Comment: Tht's typically the use case of node.js, so you should not be blocked with this. Can you show the code of your map reduce operation in node.js?

Comment: Please check the code @tomsoft